# Dart/Flutter path.contains() not returning expected result

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, path, contains

I am creating a flutter application where I need to detect clicks from a `CustomPaint` widget with my own custom painter. The paint objects are being painted based on a given `Path` object. My `CustomPainter` is overriding `hitTest` with `return path.contains(position)`.

The problem I am having is the method returns inconsistent results.

- Two point path: `Path()..moveTo(40, 80)..lineTo(100, 20);`
  The hitTest will always return false, even when I click within the line.
- Three point path: `Path()..moveTo(40, 80)..lineTo(100, 20)..lineTo(300, 60);` The hitTest works as expected.
- Complex path: `Path()..moveTo(50, 100)..lineTo(50, 150)..lineTo(200, 150)..lineTo(200, 250)..lineTo(400, 250)..lineTo(400, 100);` The hitTest returns true more than expected. Takes clicks in between paths.

Here is my sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  int boxCount = 0;
  int pathCount = 0;

  final Path path1 = Path()
    ..moveTo(40, 80)
    ..lineTo(100, 20);

  final Path path2 = Path()
    ..moveTo(40, 80)
    ..lineTo(100, 20)
    ..lineTo(300, 60);

  final Path path3 = Path()
    ..moveTo(50, 100)
    ..lineTo(50, 150)
    ..lineTo(200, 150)
    ..lineTo(200, 250)
    ..lineTo(400, 250)
    ..lineTo(400, 100);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => print("path clicked ${++pathCount}"),
            child: CustomPaint(
              size: MediaQuery.of(context).size,
              painter: MyCustomPainter(path3),
            )));
  }
}

class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Path path;
  final Paint myPaint = Paint()
    ..strokeWidth = 2
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

  int clickCount = 0;
  MyCustomPainter(this.path);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, myPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset position) {
    return path.contains(position);
  }
}
```

Comment: draw your path with `PaintingStyle.fill` - area drawn in black color will return `true` for `Path.contains` method

Comment: @pskink I see. Is there any way to get it so the hit test is more in line with what I expected? Where it would only return true if the position was in the path with a stroke style?

Comment: i dont think so